# Decrement a Redis counter every "x" seconds

Tags: redis, distributed-computing

I have use case where I need to decrement a redis every "x" seconds. Is there a way to to do this in Redis? Redis has "aeCreateTimeEvent", but then is it exposed to clients?

If we do this externally from Redis, we need a reliable way to do invoke code to decrement the  counter stored in Redis.

By reliable, I mean this: failure of the node hosting the "decrement every "x" secs" program, should not to lead to the failure of this setup.

That said probably having a distributed program to decrement sounds like a lot of work. So it is preferable to have something built-in within Redis.

Answer (score 4):

No, `aeCreateTimeEvent` as all simple event library (described in `AE_H`) used only in Redis internals. But here is realy nothing hard to do this with some small Redis server patching.

We use that way for a similar problem:

1. Patch `serverCron` function from `redic.s` to add new entry with custom code  with `run_with_period` macro.
2. Add keys you need to decrement to some special list.
3. Iterate this keys in your custom function.

I think this may be very cool idea for Redis server - add ability to add custom LUA scripts to Redis cron pipeline. This allow to turn Redis to some kind of LUA application server.

### If consistency important

1. Add `last update` time with last time you make decrement.
2. Update `last update` each time you make decrement.
3. Check value of `last update` to determin decrement step: (current_time - last_update) mod X * decrement_step.

This allow you recover right decremented value if server crash.